# How to determine if give a property isn't inherited from base class?

Tags: c++, qt, properties, moc

How to determine if give a property isn't  inherited from base class? I'm converting an object to a `QVariantList` and I'd like to keep out of my `list` the inherited properties from base class, like `objectName` from `QObject`

```
 QVariantList list;
 const QMetaObject *meta = obj->metaObject();
            for(int i = 0, len = meta->propertyCount(); i < len; ++i)
            {
                QMetaProperty prop = meta->property(i);
                if(porp isn't inherited from base class) {
                  const char *name = prop.name();
                  QVariant value = obj->property(name);
                  QVariantMap map;
                  map.insert(name, value);
                  list.append(map);
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are always counted from the most-base (that is `QObject`) to the most-derived class (the type of the instance). Each level of inheritance has its own `QMetaObject` and adds properties **on top of** the previous ones, where the counting continues.

Each class, represented by its `QMetaObject`, has a property *offset* (that is the ID of the first property introduced by that class) and the property *count* (that is the ID of the last property plus one). If you want to only iterate over the properties introduced by the `QMetaObject *meta` (excluding the inherited ones), then start counting from the *offset*:

```
for(int i = meta->propertyOffset(), len = meta->propertyCount(); i < len; ++i)
```

Alternatively, if you want to count the properties introduced *since* another class, represented by another `QMetaObject *base`, then start counting from its *property count* since this by its definition is the last property of that class plus one which is equal to the first of the least-derived-since-the-base.

```
for(int i = base->propertyCount(), len = meta->propertyCount(); i < len; ++i)
```

The above methods are equal if `base` represents the direct base class of the class represented by `meta`. They are however not equal if there are more classes in between.